# Matlab neural network error: Input 1 size does not match net.inputs{1}.size

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have a 90×50 matrix that holds my train data. every row holds features extracted from input images of digits (90 images have been read - 10 images for every digits). First 10 rows are extracted from 10 images of digit `1`, the second 10 rows are extracted from 10 images digit `2`, and so on, hence `size(dataset,1) = 90`

Neural networks part of my code is shown below:

```
T=zeros(1,90);
for  i=1:90
    T(i)=ceil(i/10);
end
setdemorandstream(491218382);
net=fitnet(20);

[net,tr]=train(net,datasetNormalized',T);
```

datasetNormalized is my dataset normalized in the [0 1] interval. T is target for network. 
What I want to do now is get a new image of a digit, turning it into a 1×50 vector(m_normalized in this case) and guess with the help of my trained network which digit it is. I used the code below but it does generate errors:

```
[a,b]=max(sim(net,m_normalized));
disp(b);
 msgbox(['digit is: ' num2str(b)],'Digit recognized','help');
```

**Error message reads like this:**

```
Error using network/sim (line 130)
Input 1 size does not match net.inputs{1}.size.

Error in Neural (line 92)
[a,b]=max(sim(net,m_normalized));
```

Do you have any idea how I can get an output from the script that shows me which digit the input image was?
By the way, the full script code is here for further reference:

```
clc
clear
close all

numOfPhotos = 90;
imgRows = 100;
imgCols = 50;
X = zeros(numOfPhotos, (imgRows * imgCols) / 100);

%% Resize Images
% myresize(imgRows,imgCols);

% read train images
datasetIndex = 0;    

for i = 1:numOfPhotos/10
    for j = 1:numOfPhotos/9           
        datasetIndex = datasetIndex+1;
        im = imread(['resized_train_numbers\' num2str(i) ' (' num2str(j) ').jpg']);
        im = im2bw(im, graythresh(im));    

        c = 1;
        for g = 1:imgRows/10
            for e = 1:imgCols/10
                s = sum(sum(im((g*10-9 : g*10),(e*10-9 : e*10))));
                X(datasetIndex, c) = s;
                c = c+1;            
            end    
        end
    end
end

datasetNormalized = zeros(numOfPhotos, imgRows*imgCols/100);
%% Normalize dataset contents
minDataset = min(min(X));
maxDataset = max(max(X));
for i = 1:numOfPhotos
    for j = 1:imgRows*imgCols/100
        datasetNormalized(i, j) = (X(i, j) - minDataset) / (maxDataset - minDataset);
    end
end

%%Neural network part

T = zeros(1, 90);
for  i = 1:90
    T(i) = ceil(i/10);
end

setdemorandstream(491218382);
net = fitnet(20);
[net, tr]=train(net, datasetNormalized', T);

% Read input image for recognition

newImg = imread('plate_1\1.jpg');
newImg = imresize(newImg, [imgRows imgCols]);
newImg = im2bw(newImg, graythresh(newImg));
scrsz = get(0, 'ScreenSize');
figure('Position', [1 1 scrsz(3)/3 scrsz(4)/2]),
imshow(newImg);

m = zeros(1, imgRows*imgCols/100);
c = 1;
for g = 1:imgRows/10
    for e = 1:imgCols/10
        s = sum(sum(newImg((g*10-9 : g*10), (e*10-9 : e*10))));
        m(c) = s;
        c = c+1;            
    end
end

%Normalize m contents
m_normalized = zeros(1, imgRows*imgCols/100);
for i = 1:imgRows*imgCols/100    
    m_normalized(i) = (m(i)-min(m)) / (max(m)-min(m));
end

[a,b] = max(sim(net, m_normalized));
disp(b);
msgbox(['digit is: ' num2str(b)], 'Digit recognized', 'help');
```

Comment: Why you don't check `Input 1 size` and `net.inputs{1}.size` to be the same?

Comment: Maybe I don't know what sections they are exactly in my code: this is what matlab says: `>> net.inputs{1}

ans = 

    Neural Network Input

              name: 'Input'
    feedbackOutput: []
       processFcns: {'fixunknowns', removeconstantrows,
                    mapminmax}
     processParams: {1x3 cell array of 2 params}
   processSettings: {1x3 cell array of 3 settings}
    processedRange: [50x2 double]
     processedSize: 50
             range: [50x2 double]
              size: 50
          userdata: (your custom info)` Does matlab mean 'net' by "Input 1"?

Comment: I think you should check `m_normalized` size and `net.input{1}`size

Comment: m_normalized is a 1x50 vector and net.inputs{1}.size is 50. Hey man! I transposed m_normalized when sent as parameter to fix(). Error gone! but it always gives 1 as result, no matter what digit's image I give to it.

Comment: Then I think you have problem with training and what you choose for your probably MLP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

size of the inputs used for training neural networks and inputs used to simulate network after training have to match. In the question above, input was a 50x90 matrix. Every column representing a digit. There is a corresponding output for every column. so simulation result (output) is assigned into one variable(b) and then displayed. 
The code that generated error above was like this:
`b=sim(net,m_normalized);`
Since m_normalized is an input, it has to match the columns used to train the network. Let's say it is one of the columns. so we have to transpose it to make a 50x1 vector to match the 50x90 form of training inputs:
`b=sim(net,m_normalized');` 
fixes the error.