# Neural Network toolbox MATLAB error: input does not match net.input(1).size

Tags: image, matlab, matrix

My question is similar to this link :

[Matlab neural network error: Input 1 size does not match net.inputs{1}.size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294252/matlab-neural-network-error-input-1-size-does-not-match-net-inputs1-size/35999384?noredirect=1#comment59651900_35999384)

But I cant figure out the answer to it
I am training the neural network to classify my image into two classes: foreground and background. It is basically for image segmentation.

Right now I have taken one picture and calculated different features on it: like passed filters for mean, std dev, entropy, kurtosis etc. So I have 7 different features.
I convert each matrix into a vector using (:) operator. Then stack them as a feature matrix which is of size 7 x 307200 (307200 is the mxn size of the image)
Also I have target matrix which is my ground truth 1 x 307200

I train it using the nntool and even tried the nprtool in MATLAB 2016b

When I supply the test image which is of size 1x307200 I get the following error

Input data sizes do not match net.inputs{1}.size.

I dont understand what is wrong in here ?

Comment: Are you sure you're using MATLAB 2016b?

Comment: Sorry it is MATLAB 2016a